# Why the data isn't saved in the relationship tables?

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks

I've have this DB Model http://www.dropmocks.com/mBgqjs and I'm using CakePHP to build a simple application just for learning where I have this add() method:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post') && is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Information']['picture']['tmp_name'])) {
        // Handling file uploads
        $upload_avatar_dir = WWW_ROOT . "uploads/avatar/";
        $new_file_name = $this->createRandomString() . substr($this->request->data['Information']['picture']['name'], -4);
        move_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Information']['picture']['tmp_name'], $upload_avatar_dir . $new_file_name);

        $this->request->data['Information']['picture'] = $upload_avatar_dir . $new_file_name;

        $this->Information->create();

        if ($this->Information->saveAssociated($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The information has been saved'), 'flash_success');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The information could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'flash_error');
        }
    }
    $countries = $this->Information->Country->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('countries'));
}
```

and this is my add.ctp file:

```
<div class="information form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Information', array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Add Information'); ?></legend>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#personal" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo __('Personal') ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="#extra" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo __('Other Information') ?></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="personal">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span4">
                    <?php
                        echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label' => __('Name')));
                        echo $this->Form->input('lastname');
                        echo $this->Form->input('email');
                        echo $this->Form->input('countries_id');
                        echo $this->Form->input('mobile_phone');
                        echo $this->Form->input('home_phone');
                    ?>
                </div><!--./span4-->
                <div class="span4">
                    <?php
                        echo $this->Form->input('address', array('cols' => 50, 'rows' => 5));
                        echo $this->Form->input('picture', array('type' => 'file'));
                        echo $this->Form->input('recruitment_status', array('label' => __('Status'),'options'=>array('1'=>__('Call for Interview'),'2'=>__('Rejected'),'3'=>__('Pending for Upcoming Oportunities'))));
                    ?>
                </div><!--./span4-->
            </div><!--./row-->
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="extra">
            <?php
                echo $this->Form->input('Education.0.education_content');
                echo $this->Form->input('Experience.0.experience_content');
                //echo $this->Form->input('Attachment.attachment_route', array('type' => 'file', 'multiple'));
                echo $this->Form->input('other_information');
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<?php 
 $options = array(
'value' => __('Save!'),
'class' => 'btn btn-inverse'
 );
?>  
<div class="paginator-footer"> <?php echo $this->Form->end($options);?> </div>
</div>
```

but something is wrong there because the associated data never is saved and can't find what is wrong? Can any help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your relations are correctly created in the models and use saveAll instead of saveAssociated, as the saveAssociated can't handle saving multiple entries at one time. What saveAll does is basically combining saveMany and saveAssociated into one single save method.

Comment: Well my model for Information is this http://pastebin.com/UGTxPkuK and I think it's fine, take a look please and I'm using also saveAll but without success

Comment: Don't know if it'll fix it, but try changing this:
public $hasMany = array(
    'Educations' => array(
        ...
    ),
    'Experiences' => array(
        ...
    ),
    'Attachments' => array(
        ...
    )
);

to
public $hasMany = array(
    'Education' => array(
        ...
    ),
    'Experience' => array(
        ...
    ),
    'Attachment' => array(
        ...
    )
);

Comment: Wow ... you save my day Caio, thanks a lot. I have another related question can I ask here or need to open another post for this purpose?

Comment: Open up another post. It's good so if someone has the same question they can find it with ease.